# Parameter with type of IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> accepts List<List<string>> while IEnumerable<(int, IEnumerable<string>)> doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class

```
public class Test
{
    public void M1(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> p) { }
    public void M2(IEnumerable<(int, IEnumerable<string>)> p) { }
}
var t = new Test();
```

And the following code works fine.

```
var d1 = new List<List<string>> { new List<string>{ "test" } };
t.M1(d1);
```

However, the following code gets the error

```
var d2 = new List<(int, List<string>)> { (1, new List<string>{ "test" }) };
t.M2(d2);
```

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(int, System.Collections.Generic.List)>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(int, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)>'

`d2` has to be defined as

```
var d2 = new List<(int, IEnumerable<string>)> { (1, new List<string>{ "test" }) };
```

Parameter with type of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` accepts `List<List<string>>` while `IEnumerable<(int, IEnumerable<string>)>` doesn't accept `List<(int, List<string>)>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

`IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant so you can assign a more derived type of T and all will be fine => `IEnumerable<Base> b = new List<DerivedFromBase>();`

But in your case `IEnumerable<(int, IEnumerable<string>)>` is the same as `IEnumerable<ValueTuple<int, IEnumerable<string>>>` and because `ValueTuple<int, List<string>>` is not a derived type from `ValueTuple<int, IEnumerable<string>>`you cannot use it that way.

*Update thanks to @JeppeStigNielsen*

The main reason is because covariant never works with value types and the new tuples of C# 7 are **value types**, and also `ValueType<T1, T2>` is not covariant in T2

Comment: The true reason is that the covariance of `IEnumerable<out T>` does not apply when `T` is a ___value type___. Co- and contravariance in generics of .NET never work for value types. The new tuples of C# 7 are value types. __EDIT:__ The reason you give is also correct! [`ValueTuple<T1, T2>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt744804.aspx) is not covariant in `T2`. No `class` or `struct` is covariant.

Comment: `(int, IEnumerable<string>)` is of type `ValueTuple<int, IEnumerable<string>>`.